# Why is nothing getting logged to console on this line, but everything around it works?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I am getting started playing with Chrome extensions and passing messages between the content script and the background script. I've followed some tutorials and it is going pretty well, but there is an issue I am having with passing a message with a URL and not being able to always interact with it. The simplest example I can come up with is just logging the URL. I can use the URL and my new tab opens meaning my code is working for its intention. Heck, I even tried just logging some text and it will not go to the console.

```
// background.js

// Called when the user clicks on the browser action.
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function (tab) {
    // Send a message to the active tab
    chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, function (tabs) {
        var activeTab = tabs[0];
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(activeTab.id, { "message": "clicked_browser_action" });
    });
});

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
        if (request.message === "open_new_tab") {
            console.log("Does this get logged?"); // This is not getting logged
            console.log("passedUrl: " + request.url); // This is not getting logged
            chrome.tabs.create({ "url": request.url }); // This works fine
        }
    }
);


// JavaScript source code
// content.js
console.log("hello"); // This gets logged

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
        if (request.message === "clicked_browser_action") {
            var firstHref = $("a[href^='http']").eq(0).attr("href");

            console.log(firstHref); // This gets logged

            chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ "message": "open_new_tab", "url": firstHref });
        }
    }   
);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where to read console messages from background.js in a Chrome extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10257301/where-to-read-console-messages-from-background-js-in-a-chrome-extension)

Comment: It did thank you. I need to learn to search stackoverflow better. I thought it was something wrong with my code. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

User Dafang Cao gave the answer. Thank you! It is the link ON YOUR EXTENSION in the extension list of chrome://extensions. So easy!